# Infinite Loop 2nd time around using scanner

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I have the following: I'm well aware that I have an exception I have to catch if entered input isn't numeric, what is driving me crazy is only on the first run through does this function as intended up until this point. When I request the user to enter in their weight it goes into an infinite loop on the `while(!isNum)`. I would have thought that closing down the scanner, and upon the second run re-creating the object would have created a stopping point allowing the user to enter data as it does go one. I'm utilizing Eclipse Kepler, new to the IDE and Java, working on comparing this to C# as a beginner. A little guidance would be appreciated.

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;

import org.omg.CORBA.DynAnyPackage.TypeMismatch;

public class TheValidator {

private int height;
private int weight;
private boolean isNotValid = true;
private boolean weightIsValid = false;
private Scanner sc;

void inputTest(){
    while (!isNotValid);{
        System.out.print("Please enter your height in inches.");
        numTest();
    }
    isNotValid = true;
    while (!isNotValid);{
        System.out.print("Please enter your weight in inches.");
        numTest();
    }
    sc.close();
}


void numTest()
{
    // Variable to see if entered data is legit number. 
    while(isNotValid)
    {
        boolean isNum = false;
        boolean isPos = false;
        int num = 0;

        while(!isNum)
        {
            if(sc.hasNextInt())
            {
                isNum = true;
                num = sc.nextInt();
                if(num > 0)
                {
                    isPos = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("You entered a number that is not positive. Please ensure you entered a positive numeric number and try again.");
                }                       
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("What you entered isn't even a number. Please ensure you entered a positive numeric number and try again.");
            }           
        }
        if(isNum && isPos)
        {
            isNotValid = false;
        }
    }   
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that if `hasNextInt()` is false, you need to do something to get the scanner past the illegal input.  If you don't, the scanner's cursor (which points to the next input to be looked at) will remain in the same place forever and ever, leading to an infinite loop.  If you execute this when `hasNextInt()` is false:

```
sc.nextLine();
```

that will flush out everything else on the line, allowing the user to type in new input.

This fix isn't enough; when I added this, I got other exceptions, which I think are related to the fact that you're opening a new `Scanner` for each input line.  This shouldn't be necessary.  You can initialize `sc` to a new `Scanner` when a `TheValidator` is created; and you might need to add a `close` method to `TheValidator` that closes the scanner.

Comment: I guess I was a bit confused by the wording of what the [nextLine()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextline.htm) actually did. It discussed this method "advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped". Sort of confusing for me I guess. I did make some mods to the above with success. To your point ajb nextLine() does act sort of like a reset if I'm understanding this correctly. I think I need the hasNextInt() because it is what I'm using to validate that what is entered is actually numeric in nature. Appreciate the pointers

Comment: @TargetofGravity `nextLine()` does return the input that was skipped, so you could say `String line = sc.nextLine()` if you wanted to.  There are a lot of uses where you'd want to retrieve the rest of the line and work with it.  Here I didn't assign anything to the result, which means we just throw it out, but what we really want is just the effect that skips over the current line (and thus forces the user to enter another line when we ask the scanner for more data).